# A simple mail() form in PHP stopped sending proper e-mails

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a simple mail() contact form in a website that sends info to an e-mail. Suddenly it stopped working, it stopped sending e-mails, help me, I don't know why, here is the code:

```
 <div class="form">
<form id="mail-form" action="" method="POST">
<label for="subject">Name:</label><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"><br>
<label for="from">Email:</label><input type="text" name="from" id="from"><br>
<label for="number">Phone number:</label><input type="text" name="number" id="number" /> <br>

<label id="msg" for="message">Message:</label><br><textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" class="button" id="send" name="sbm" value="Send" /><span class="button" id="clear">Refresh</span>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sbm'])){
$email_address = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$feedback = $_POST['message'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

function filter_email_header($form_field) {  
return preg_replace('/[nr|!/<>^$%*&]+/','',$form_field);
}

// $email_address  = filter_email_header($email_address);



$subjc ="From: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode('Reservation')."?= \r\n";

$email_addressP = '<html lang="bg"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>'.$email_address.'</body></html>';
$feedbackS = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/plain charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>'.$feedback.'</body></html>';
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";

$sent = mail('vb@gmail.com', $subjc , 'Name: ' . $subject .'<br>' . 'Email of the sender:  ' . $email_addressP . '<br>' . 'Message: ' . $feedbackS . '<br>' . ' Number: '. $number, $headers );
}
if (isset($sent)) {
echo '<div id="success">Successfuly sent</div>';
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Your body is misformed, `'<html><head><<meta '` (check the double `<<`) but that's probably not the cause. Check your *From*, your SMTP provider

Comment: @Cid I edited that too, the problem is that if an e-mail is sent, I just get an e-mail with the proper subject but without any content

Comment: Have you tested sending to  a different email address? If it was working before and not now with no changes made to the script, perhaps your email client itself is the cause?

Comment: tried a few different e-mails, yes, strangely nothing happens

Comment: Can you try sending a simple non-html string as the body? What happens then?

Comment: Well it doesn’t seem to be a problem of the hosting or something, the problem is in the form itself or in how I declare the data

Comment: So did it send properly when using simple text, or no?

Comment: Only when it was send without including the encodings, the variables and the if statements, it got sent with simple strings in mail(‘vlad@gmail.com’, ‘test’, ‘test’, ‘test’);